# run webkit WebView without GTK?

Tags: webkit, gtk

Can I run [webkit.WebView](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-load-uri) object without [GTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B#GTK.2B_hello_world) loop? I want to make a simple webkit-based headless browser and I do not need GTK anywhere - I don't display anything.

```
win = gtk.Window() # <------------------------+--- can I not use those?
web = webkit.WebView() #                       |
web.load_uri("http://example.com") #           |
web.connect("load-finished", get_html_source) #|
win.add(web) # <-------------------------------|
#win.show_all() #                              |
gtk.main() # <---------------------------------|
```

True that without `show_all` I don not display anything, but I still use GTK. I want to make the script multi threading and GTK is problematic here (the less modules I use the better for me)

(I use Python but this is not a python-specific question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is impossible. `webkit.WebView` is built on top of the GTK toolkit and even if you are only displaying a web view, you still need a GTK window to put it in.

If you really don't want a GTK window, then why not open the page in the default browser?

Comment: I want to make simple, automatic headless browser with JavaScript. It can be done easily with `gtk` and `webkit`, but I also want it to be used with `multithreading`

Comment: That is not a good explanation of why it is impossible (if that is actually the case, I'm still looking for it).
It makes perfect sense to not want a GTK window. I have a similar need, I'd like WebView to use the whole display directly with the minimum dependencies possible, hence GTK is a burden.

Comment: You may have your reasons for not wanting a GTK window, but then you are using the wrong tool for the job. `webkit.WebView` comes from the WebKitGTK library, which as the name suggests, requires GTK.

Answer (score 2):

For a headless you can also use `gtk_offscreen_window_new()`. For `gtk_main()` and multi-threading consider [reading the article "Multi-threaded GTK applications"](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness).